# how to drag and drop files into a div without repeating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>songs list</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
.droppable {
  width: 300;
  height: 900px;
  background: lightgrey;

}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="draggable">
    <p><a href="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\drag and drop\static\Allah Duhai Hai.mp3"><EM> barish</EM></p> 
</div>
<div class="draggable">
    <p><a href="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\drag and drop\static\Aa Bhi Ja Mere Mehermaan.mp3"><EM> Aa Bhi Ja Mere Mehermaan</EM></a></p>
</div>
    <div class="draggable">
<p><a href="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\drag and drop\static\Aa Bhi Ja Sanam.mp3"><EM>Aa Bhi Ja Sanam</EM></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="draggable">
<p><a href="C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\drag and drop\static\Allah Duhai Hai.mp3"><EM>Allah Duhai Hai </EM></a></p>
    </div>

<div class="droppable">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    stack: ".draggable",
    helper: 'clone'
});
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var droppable = $(this);
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        // Move draggable into droppable
        draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html
```

#i have script for drag and drop drop audio files it works fine , but if i upload same audio once again into div it, goes again into that div, what i mean is i don't want to add that file if it is added once (i.e) drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the class from the div after you complete the script using the `.removeClass()` method (https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    stack: ".draggable",
    helper: 'clone'
});
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var droppable = $(this);
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        // Move draggable into droppable
        draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
        $(this).removeClass('droppable');
    }
});
</script>
```